# Enable Button when two strings match certain criteria Angular 7

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 7 and would like to disable a button whenever two inputs are not matching specified criteria.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="placeholder"/>
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="identifier" placeholder="identifier"/>

<button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-raised ui-button-rounded" label="Click me!" disabled="{{validateIdentifier() && name.length > 0}}"></button>
```

TS:

```
 private identifier: string = "";
 private name: string = "";

 validateIdentifier(): boolean {
    const REGEXP = new RegExp(/[EHIS]-[0-9]{9}/);
    return REGEXP.test(this.identifier);
}
```

So when I insert a string matching the following regex: `(E|H|I|S)-[0-9]{9}` and the length of the inserted `name`-attribute is at least 1, I'd like to have my button enabled, else not.

Sadly my button is (and stays) disabled on any input. What did I do wrong on that?

Comment: try `[disabled]="validateIdentifier() && name.length > 0"`

Comment: Can you give the string that you were trying to input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a slight error in your boolean logic. I think you want to negate the result of `validateIdentifier()` and say if not vailidateIdentifier or the length is 0 then disable. E.G.

```
<button
  pButton
  type="button"
  class="ui-button-raised ui-button-rounded"
  label="Click me!"
  [disabled]="!validateIdentifier() || name.length === 0">
</button>
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I had a mistake there since I want `[disabled]` to be `false` when the criteria match so the button get's enabled, good point!. Actually, as @ABOS also stated, I missed the brackets around the `disabled`. Thanks for that to the both of you :) - going to accept this answer since you stated both mistakes (implicitly)